# Laravel article image slideshow

Tags: php, laravel, image, slideshow

I've got a Laravel project where you can create articles and so on. Of course I want to have an image slideshow with multiple images per article. I've managed to save multiple images in the database in one column via implode. [PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObWoE.png)

How do I display the slideshow now? I have no idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is the one @Sang Nguyen posted: The opposite of [`implode()`](http://php.net/explode) is [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode).

However I am going to add a more "Laravel-like" way of doing it:

Assuming you have an `Article` model, add an accessor:

```
class Article extends Model {
    ...
    public function getImagesListAttribute() {
        return collect(explode('|', $this->images));
    }
    ...
}
```

Then:

```
$article = Article::find(1);

var_dump($article->images_list); //would be a Collection of strings (which are your image names)
```

More about accessors: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

More about collections: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections

Comment: Where do I put the var_dump($article->images_list); ?

Comment: @jonasm You can use it in your `views` to display the images in carousels/slideshows.

Comment: okay it works. now I have to link them correctly. it gives me the url of the site and then the image name

Comment: Where do you store the images?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `explode` your data from database then show it

```
$images = explode('|', $post->image);

@foreach ($images as $image)
   <img src="{{ url($image) }} alt="image" />
@endforeach
```

Then you can use OwlCarousel https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/ to create slideshow.

You can create a basic slider with this example https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html

Example: In your blade view

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    @foreach (explode('|', $post->image) as $image)
       <div class="item"><img src="{{ url($image) }} alt="image" /></div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```